# How can i get area of data like contour?

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the area of shape enclosed with outside data in the plot.

[What i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqkfm.png)

I want to connect the with outside data and make shape.
And finally, want to calculate the area of shape.

How can I get it?

Should I use the contour code for it or is there other way for it?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the area of a shape enclosed by outside data in a plot, you can indeed use contour detection. You save the plot as an image and read the image using the below code to find the area

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image or plot data
image = cv2.imread("your_image.jpg")  # Replace "your_image.jpg" with the path to your image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply thresholding to create a binary image
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find contours in the binary image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Select the contour with the largest area
largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Calculate the area of the contour
area = cv2.contourArea(largest_contour)

print("Area:", area)
```